# Gradient of $X \mapsto \mbox{Tr} \left(\left(AXA\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}\right)$

Tags: matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus, scalar-fields

I need to find the gradient of

$$ X \mapsto \mbox{Tr} \left(\left(AXA\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}\right) $$

where both $X$ and $A$ are symmetric matrices.

I know that the derivative of $\mbox{Tr} \left(AXA\right)$ is $A^{2}$ using equation (101) on page 12 of the Matrix Cookbook. However, I have the trace of the square root of a matrix product, which makes it complicated. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why do you need the derivative? Take a look at the nuclear norm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define two new symmetric matrices 
$$\eqalign{
M &= AXA \cr
Q &= M^{-\frac{1}{2}} \cr
}$$
Write the function in terms this new variable, then find its differential and gradient.
$$\eqalign{
 \phi &= {\rm tr}\Big(M^{\frac{1}{2}}\Big) \cr
d\phi
 &= \tfrac{1}{2}Q:dM
  = \tfrac{1}{2}Q:A\,dX\,A 
  = \tfrac{1}{2}AQA:dX \cr
\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial X} &= \tfrac{1}{2}AQA \cr\cr
}$$
In some steps above, a colon was used to denote the trace/Frobenius product, i.e.
$$\eqalign{B:C={\rm tr}(B^TC)}$$

Comment: $\frac{\partial Tr\left(X^{k}\right)}{\partial X}=k {X^{k-1}}^{T}$ Matrix cookbook page 13 expression (121). I think there should not be any trace when you define $\eqalign{

d\phi
 &= \tfrac{1}{2}Q:dM}$. I see that the trace disappears in the last step.$\eqalign{
 \frac{\partial\phi}{\partial X} &= \tfrac{1}{2}AQA \cr\cr
}$

Comment: Also $\eqalign{
M &= AXA \cr
Q &= M^{-\frac{1}{2}} \cr
}$ assumes the matrix product is invertible. What to do if it is not ?

Comment: If $M$ is singular, I'm not sure you can take its square root (which is the premise of your question).

Comment: M could be positive semi definite and it that case it has a square root but it is not invertible.

Comment: @greg Does this hold when $A$ and $X$ are complex matrices, i.e. Hermitian?

Comment: @user1239110 Not quite. If you redo the calculation using Hermitian matrices you will find that 
$$\eqalign{
\def\h{\tfrac 12}
\def\g#1#2{\frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}}
\g{\phi}{X} &= \h(AQA)^T \\
}$$
Note that $(M,A,X)$ are hermitian but $Q$ is not.