# Second derivative of a matrix function

Tags: matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus

I am trying to find the $\textit{second}$ derivative of $X \mapsto (F \circ G) (X)$, where $G(X)=\frac{AXA}{\operatorname{tr}(AXA)}$ and $F(X)=\operatorname{tr}\left((CXC)^\frac{1}{2}\right)$ are functions of the positive matrix X. The matrices A and C are constant and also positive.

I computed the first derivative and got

$\frac{\partial (F \circ G)}{\partial X}=\frac{1}{2}\operatorname{tr}\left( AXA\right)^{-1}\left(AC(CG(X)C)^{-\frac{1}{2}}CA -\operatorname{tr} \left((CG(X)C)^\frac{1}{2} \right)A^2\right)$

notably thanks to:

[Derivative of $\mbox{Tr} \left(\left(AXA\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}\right)$ with respect to $X$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2800228/derivative-of-mboxtr-left-leftaxa-right-frac12-right-with-respe?rq=1)

[Derivative of $X \mapsto \frac{AXA}{\operatorname{Tr} \left( AXA \right )}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4498448/derivative-of-x-mapsto-fracaxa-operatornametr-left-axa-right)

However, to derive again, I am stuck with the inverse square root $(CG(X)C)^{-\frac{1}{2}}$. Would you know how to deal with it?

Comment: For the second derivative, are you expecting a rank 4 tensor?

Comment: [Here's](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3938531/357854) one way to differentiate matrix square roots. And matrix inverses are differentiated as $$dA^{-1} = -A^{-1} \;dA\;A^{-1}$$

Comment: Also, note that ultimately the only problem term is of the form $B(B^T XB)^{-1/2}B^T$, where $B = AC$. So as long as you can get that one, the rest is all differentiating traces.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. If I get it right, we have

$\frac{\partial \left(X^{-\frac{1}{2}}\right)}{\partial X}=X^{-\frac{1}{2}} \Gamma(X) X^{-\frac{1}{2}}$
where $\Gamma(X)$ is a fourth order tensor whose components are given by $\Gamma(X)_{ijkl}=\left( \left( X^\frac{1}{2} \bigoplus X^\frac{1}{2} \right)^{-1}\right)_{\alpha \beta}$ with $\alpha=i+(j-1)n$ and $\beta=k+(l-1)n ~$  (if X is a $n\times n$ matrix).

Then:

$\frac{\partial \left((B^TXB)^{-\frac{1}{2}}\right)}{\partial X}=B(B^TXB)^{-\frac{1}{2}} \Gamma(B^TXB) (B^TXB)^{-\frac{1}{2}}B^T$

Comment: Now what could be the derivative of $X \mapsto B (B^TXB)^{-\frac{1}{2}}B^T$ ? I know the derivative of $X \mapsto B X B^T$ and $X \mapsto (B^TXB)^{-\frac{1}{2}}$, but I'm not sure how the composition rule works with tensors...

Comment: If you just want to compute this gradient for some examples use [JAX](https://github.com/google/jax). If you really need the derivative symbolically: what for? It's likely going to be a rather complex and unwieldy expression.

Comment: Okay, my aim is to show that if $tr \left( \left(A \frac{AXA}{tr(AXA)} A \right)^{\frac{1}{2}} \right) = tr \left( \left(B \frac{BXB}{tr(BXB)} B \right)^{\frac{1}{2}} \right)$ for all positive matrix $X$, then necessarily $A=B$.

(A and B are positive and $tr(A^2)=tr(B^2)=1$).

My idea was to take the derivative and evaluate it at $X=Id$ for example. At first order, this is equal to zero on both sides. I think the dependency in A or B appears at the second order, but, as you said, it is hard to compute.

Comment: To avoid [XY-problems](https://xyproblem.info/) you should always post the motivation in the question. Though to be honest even this problem you presented now reeks like an XY-problem as well.